# Error with negative numbers when calculating the sum of digits of the number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I gotta calculate the sum of digits of the number. It works for positive numbers but not for negative ones. What should i add here?

```
n = int(input("Input a number: ")) 
suma = 0
while(n > 0):
    if n > 0:
        last = n % 10
        suma += last
        n = n // 10
print("The sum of digits of the number is: ", suma)
```

Input/Output

```
Input a number: -56
The sum of digits of the number is:  0
```

Comment: try changing `n > 0` to `n != 0` and remove if judgement

Comment: Try to `import math` first, then n = `math.abs(n)` should work for pos/negative numbers.

Comment: work with the `abs()` value of the input? [ref docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple fix is to do `n = abs(n)` then it will work with your code.

And if you really `*lazy*` you could simplify the approach to this:

```
n = abs(n)

sum_digit =  sum(int(x) for x in str(n))  # are we cheating?  ;-)
```

Comment: Similar way: `sum_tot = sum(map(int, str(n)))`  - but not recommend.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a negative number, the first while loop's condition `while(n > 0):` will be false, hence the following code will never be executed and sum's value will never be updated and remain 0.

Use `abs()` function to get absolute value.

```
n = abs(int(input("Input a number: ")))
suma = 0
while n > 0:
    if n > 0:
        last = n % 10
        suma += last
        n = n // 10
print("The sum of digits of the number is: ", suma)
```

Comment: This will not work.  Have you check it?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it now, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could utilize [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) and [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```py
def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")


def get_sum_of_digits(num: int) -> int:
    num = abs(num)
    total = 0
    while num:
        num, digit = divmod(num, 10)
        total += digit
    return total


def main() -> None:
    n = get_int_input("Input an integer number: ")
    sum_of_digits = get_sum_of_digits(n)
    print(f"The sum of digits of the number is: {sum_of_digits}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Input an integer number: 123456789
The sum of digits of the number is: 45
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Input an integer number: -56
The sum of digits of the number is: 11
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
Input an integer number: asdf
Error: Enter an integer, try again...
Input an integer number: 2.3
Error: Enter an integer, try again...
Input an integer number: -194573840
The sum of digits of the number is: 41
```